# Count the number of living actors that were born in London

Tags: sql

I am having some difficulty with this SQL question. The tables are not populated with any information so hard for me to check answer.

Question: Count the number of living actors that were born in London

```
dbo.actor
 ()Columns
    >actnumb
    >actname
    >birthplace
    >yearborn
    >yeardied
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: What you have tried? How do you check the provided solution is working (without data)?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actor WHERE yeardied IS NULL AND birthplace = 'London'`?

Comment: I dont know how to check, the query just has to be correct. And GMB how that wouldnt show me whether they are living or dead. Your query is partially correct i just need to know how to tell if they are living or dead.

Comment: They are all living, that was the definition of your original question "Count the number of living actors that were born in London". Can you explain?

Comment: Theres a year died table aswell so lets assume some born on 1970 and died 2010 ( these people would not be included in the result) but lets say someone was born on 1970 and their year died feild is empy since they are living. I want these people in the result. Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Count the number of living actors that were born in London

My understanding of your requirement is as follows:

- we will need an aggregate query with `COUNT()` function
- we would expect we would recognize a *living* actor by the fact that he has not death date, hence that would translate as: `yeardied IS NULL`
- column `birthplace` should be used to implement the filter on the birth place.

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actor WHERE yeardied IS NULL AND birthplace = 'London'
```

Comment: That sounds like what I’m looking for. I think i was over complicating the looking for null feilds part. I will try to populate the table tonight and try it!